# What is the best way to model this (simple composition like strategy pattern or generics)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Say I have carbase which represents bases class for all cars like honda, toyota, ford etc..). Similarly say, I also have truck base (all different vehicle categories). And also please note that each honda vehicle have some common attributes which the hondabaseobject represents.

Now, I want to define a HondaCivic; ideally it will be `hondacivic : hondacar, hondabaseobject`, but since .net doesn't allow multiple inheritance I am pondering over various ways to model it.

Objects -

1. I want to access all honda vehicles with honda base object, all cars with carbase, all trucks with truckbase etc...

Please see the below model I have come up with. I am OK with it, but for some reason I don't like the interface I defined (IHondaBaseObject)

I just defined it so that I can handle all honda vehicles with it as I know all honda vehicles composes honda base object and implements this contract.

Is there better way to handle it?

Probably something like `HondaCivic<HondaBaseObject> : HondaCar` - but handling is difficult as I cannot simply convert `HondaCivic<HondaBaseObject> as HondaBaseObject` - with the interface I can simply interchange types.

---

looks like its similar to [Multiple inheritance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474135/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp) basically achieving multiple inheritance in c#

i.e. HondaCivic : CarBase, HondaBaseObject 
<=> HondaCivic : CarBase, IHondabaseObject
{
        HondaBaseObject Honda;
}

```
   class vehicle
      {
      }
    /// <summary>
        /// Base class for all the cars (common fields and operations of car)
        /// </summary>
        class CarBase : vehicle
        {
            //parts
            virtual steering steering {get;}
            virtual void StartingTheCar(...)

            //engine
        }
        class HondaCar : CarBase
        {
//overrides
//specializations
        }
        class ToyotaCar : CarBase
        {
//overrides
//specializations
        }
        class TruckBase : vehicle
        {
//overrides
//specializations
        }
        class HondaTruck : TruckBase
        {
//overrides
//specializations
        }
        class ToyotaTruck : TruckBase
        {
//overrides
//specializations
        }
        //Is it necessary? - i introduces this so that as i want to access all types of hoda vehicles with a single type
        //but having interface, just for the sake of handling doesnt make sense?
        //i am not sure - but, looks like something is wrong.
        interface IHondaBaseObject
        {
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Object which contains the common attributes for each honda vehicle (say cars, suvs, trucks, bikes etc...)
        /// </summary>
        class HondaBaseObject 
            : IHondaBaseObject
        {
            string identity { get; set; }
            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                return base.Equals(obj);
            }
            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return base.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
        //Now what is the best way to model it? should i use generics? or just a simple stragey pattern?
        class HondaCivic : HondaCar, IHondaBaseObject
        {
            HondaCivic(HondaBaseObject ho)
            {
            }
            public HondaBaseObject { get; }
        }
```

Comment: Why not have a common ancestor to all, `Vehicle`? Since everything inherits from Vehicle, put all your shared things there. As you move down the tree of inheritance, things get more specialized. There is no need for multiple inheritance. You also might want to consider using interfaces (classes can implement multiple interfaces).

Comment: I strongly doubt the design. Class names that differ in an attribute of the type should probably not be different classes but indicate a property instead. Brand should probably be a property.

Comment: @Steve, yes i can have vehicle - basically truck,cars everything dervices from it. But i also have another base class which just represents honda attributes (note - need not be a vehicle, just some common attributes)

Comment: Sounds like you should have an `IHonda` interface. Interfaces can "inherit" from other interfaces, too.

Comment: @Erno, i just come up with hypothetical example. Please note that each class will have their own specilized fields and operatiosn. For ex: a HondaCar which is deriving from Car might totally override how the engine works and have its own custom parts.

Comment: @Steve, yes - thats why i introduces something like IHondaBaseObject whcih each Honda vehicle implements. But, please note that each honda vehicle has the same implementation for this interface. So, i introduces something called HondaBaseObject and derived it from IHOndaBaseObject and each honda vehicle composes it. But, now does honda vehicle (say HondaCiviv) can simply derves HondaCar and compose HondaBaseObejct or can also implement the IHondaBaseObject intrface. this is where i felt something is wrong.

Comment: Looks like whatever i did is the way to go - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474135/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp (using inheritance, composition and interface - to get multiple inheritance in C#)

Comment: I doubt this idea too. Consider: why didn't you create classes such as "RedCar", "BlueCar", "BlackCar", ... You might have found a way to mimmick multiple inheritance in C# but that doesn't make the design correct.

Comment: @Erno, thanks for ur thoughts. Here is my take - blue car, red car etc... just a property of a vehicle. Whereas how a engine works/runs, various different parts/attributes (for ex: a luxury car can have heated leather seats, wheras normal honda civic wont have it) etc... are sepcializations of a specific car.

Comment: Brand, type of engine, type of seats, these are all attributes of a car, NOT a specialization.

Comment: There will be some attributes and specializations. all the commoncality will be covered in base classes and specialization will be covered in the specific derived classes. you may want to concentrate more on the whole data model design rather than specific examples like color, brand etc...

Comment: I'd say this: composition over inheritance. As @ErnodeWeerd also mentions, these classes shouldn't be types on its own. They are just variations (different properties).

Comment: For the "heated seats" versus "normal seats" - you could use an enum property that can be logically ORed together. Why would these really have to be different interfaces or ancestors?

Answer (score 1):

> just come up with hypothetical example. Please note that each class
>   will have their own specilized fields and operatiosn. For ex: a
>   HondaCar which is deriving from Car might totally override how the
>   engine works and have its own custom parts.

Latest insights in best practices for OO-development is that you do not use inheritance when the classes have different (or extra) fields/methods. You should use them only when they are totally interchangable, thus all classes conforming to the same interface.

I would suggest to use a Vehicle kind of class with 2 composites, ICarBase and something like IIdentifiable.

More info on the Liskov substitution principle: http://davesquared.net/2009/01/introduction-to-solid-principles-of-oo.html

Good luck.

Comment: thanks Remco. But, please note that not all the fields/methods are specialized. for ex: as Erno pointed out there can be some common properties like color, operations like function of mirrors etc...

Comment: It's not about that they have something in common, it's about that they cannot have anything different ("anything" in the context of Liskov substitution).

Comment: I understand, one of the other principles also says Single responsibility, so group these properties in a separate class when apropriate, you should end up with 1 vehicle with something like a MirrorOperator, and a Colour property on the Vehicle.

Comment: Perhaps another good tip I recently received is: that you shouldn't try to model real world objects, but you should model the needs of your software. So an IIdentity is probably a good software thing for naming, labeling etc. the class HondaCivic is just a class who needs a ? or exposes ?. Like Erno de Weerd already said, perhaps your basic design should be polished a bit.