# Multiple inheritance by interfaces in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

It is clearly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474135/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp) how to achieve "multiple inheritance" in C# by using **Interface**. However, I wonder, how to achieve the same but in the Entity Framework Code First Workflow.

Provided code to make things clear :

```
public abstract class DomainObject {
       // Every business model must have this fields
       public Guid Id {get;set;}
       public string SystemCode {get;set;}

}
```

And here also some optional abstract classes like:

```
public abstract class MultiTitleObject : DomainObject {
       public string TitleRu { get; set; }
       public string TitleEn { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ManageableByAdminObject : DomainObject {
       public bool isVisibleOnSite {get;set;}
       public bool isDeletedByAdmin {get;set;}
}
```

Let's say that I have class that need to have fields of both **MultiTitleObject  and ManageableByAdminObject** and **DomainObject** as always rule.
Since C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, I can do the following :

```
public class ManageableByAdminDomainObject : ManageableByAdminObject { 

}
public class ManageableByAdminMultiTitleDomainObject : ManageableByAdminDomainObject {
     // Even here it's too complicated...
     // What if I need to inherit from 3 or more classes? 

}
```

So the solution I wanted to use is Interface like :

```
public interface IFieldImitation {
      bool isVisibleOnSite ();
}

public class ManageableByAdminObject : IFieldImitation, DomainObject {
      public bool isVisibleOnSite () => return true;
 }
```

However, EF does understand abstract classes but not the interfaces.
How should I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `EF does understand abstract classes but not the interfaces.`? Interface is used to achieve runtime polymorphism. It is a contract that who ever inherits from this interface MUST implement the members. You would still need to declare the interface members in your class so it's different from inheriting an abstract class.